# fresh install of API Manager 2.1: Error - No tasks assigned to the login user or no connectivity with BPS engine

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I just downloaded and installed WSO2 API Manager to a Linux server. As per the installation guide, I have not made any changes. 
The only wrinkle I had was that the wso2server.sh script did not have execute permission so I set that manually. I did not check or modify any other permissions.
After startup, I am able to access each of the Admin, Publisher and Store apps.
In the Admin app, the first screen shows the message: "No tasks assigned to the login user or no connectivity with BPS engine."

When I dig into the logs, I see this entry in wso2carbon.log
`TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-02 10:26:12,049]  WARN {JAGGERY.site.blocks.user.login.ajax.login:jag} -  Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://<BPSHost>:<BPSPort>/services/AuthenticationAdmin {JAGGERY.site.blocks.user.login.ajax.login:jag}`

the wso2-apigw-errors.log has a largely identical error

```
2017-03-02 10:26:12,049 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-17]  WARN login:jag Not Retrieving Pending Tasks. Check BPS Connectivity. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 8: https://<BPSHost>:<BPSPort>/services/AuthenticationAdmin
```

This may or may not be relevant, I am also seeing warnings about being unable to flush and lock system prefs, even though its successfully creating the directory earlier.

`TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-02 09:28:30,285]  INFO {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1} -  Created user preferences directory. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-03-02 11:11:19,058]  WARN {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences} -  Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 32645. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-03-02 11:11:19,058]  WARN {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences} -  Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock. {java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences}`

I am assuming I need to configure or download something else to get this work. Please advise!

Comment: Permission issue you are seeing is a known issue and you can find a solution in - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21599038/3176125

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your use case is. You can integrate a BPS engine with WSO2 API Manager for the following tasks.

- User Signup Workflow
- Application Creation Workflow
- Application Registration Workflow
- API Subscription Workflow

This [blog](http://blog.tharindu.org/2015/03/how-to-integrate-wso2-bps-server-with.html) explains how you can integrate WSO2 Business Process Server with WSO2 API Manager. You can check the official [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Managing+Workflow+Extensions) which explains the avaiable workflow extensions.

You are getting this warning message when you are logging to admin portal as it checks if there are any pending approval tasks. You can ignore this warning if you are not using any BPS integrations. Based on your use case you can add a BPS engine for workflows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think we will need workflows down the line. My primary question I guess was if this message was important.  I was trying to add logons to allow multiple users to access the application without sharing the admin credentials.   since this is purely a proof of concept, its probably not that important.