# Getting Warning Error in WSO2 for every 30 seconds

Tags: wso2-iot

[date time, 804] [Iot - Core] WARN - FileSystemPreferences Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 0.

[date time, 805] [Iot - Core] WARN - FileSystemPreferences Couldn't Flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.

Comment: This is just an warning message, not even a question. Try to ask a clear question on what you are looking for. Also, when it comes to error's / debugging include information on what you are doing, what is the desired behaviour and what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a JVM related issue. JVM needs write access to the /etc/.java/.systemPrefs directory, which it cannot access when run as a non-root user, see: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4838770

Try changing ownership of the /etc/.java/.systemPrefs directory to the current user [eg. wso2:wso2] using

`sudo chown -R wso2:wso2 /etc/.java/.systemPrefs`

The file will still be writable by root (as root can write to any file), but if you need multiple users to be able to write to this file you might set up a file ACL as well using:

`sudo setfacl -R -m u:wso2:rw /etc/.java/.systemPrefs`

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599038/1560536)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message under the same interval, and this fixed it i guess you need full priveliege to write execute and open on that folder.

```
chmod 777 /etc/.java/.systemPrefs/
chmod 777 /etc/.java/
```